# Can I define a typescript variable that is an enum and a function?

Tags: typescript

Here is the code so far:

```
function fr(this: any, value: number) {
  return Object.keys(this).find(k => this[k] === value);
}

type getEnumValue = (value: number) => string;
type myEnum = typeof enumVal;

enum enumVal {
  a = 1,
  b = 2
}

let EnumEval = fr.bind(enumVal) as getEnumValue | myEnum;
Object.assign(EnumEval, enumVal);

// Why are the casts required?
console.log((EnumEval as myEnum).a);
console.log((EnumEval as getEnumValue)(1));

console.log(EnumEval as myEnum.a);
console.log(EnumEval(1));
```

TS errors on the final two lines, requiring me to cast.  Why?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMATgCigCxgZwFyICGYAngDSIBuhANiAKYFggC2ARvSgJSIDeAUIkQp6UECiQB5NgCt60AHQBreiRwZsOLguAwwAEzRLEAXgB8iLLgDaSgLqmTJqrQZcA3PwC+-fvWYsiP6sAGq0fIJEpogAjGSRbNEATN6+NKKIAKIBmdQ00agKbHqGwSxhNDyEOIhoaHkMeAEc3KYWOFAoegDmiAA+tVAkAA70cMBBARVcHvzScorVODDdYGjZrLm0FGXTnvwA9AeIAOqYJIi4lpj0iBDVUML0AI4gMCL6APz8EAg4cOkFDQ4N06hsWFt8tVEOAlGA4AB3JDQoajcaTUK0bSEWa-MD-QHA0HgyFoGIzTxAA)

Comment: Can you tell me what is your motivation to use enum in such way? Enum should be used as enum, so just simple variant.

Comment: @MaciejSikora a non TS user was saying that TS couldn't handle this typing, and I was having trouble actually showing the user that it could.  Since the primary purpose of this code is to be able to get a text value or int value from the same object I did let them know that Enums in TS already solve this for you in a way simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
let EnumEval = fr.bind(enumVal) as (((value:number) => string) & (typeof enumVal));
```

Or:

```
let EnumEval = fr.bind(enumVal) as (typeof fr & typeof enumVal);
```

*Variable that is an enum **and** a function* - so it should be **[intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)** (`&`), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (`|`)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMATgCigCxgZwFyICGYAngDSIBuhANiAKYFggC2ARvSgJSIDeAUIkQp6UECiQB5NgCt60AHQBreiRwZsOLguAwwAEzRLEAXgB8iLLgDaSgLqmTJqrQZcA3PwC+-fvWYsiP6sAGq0fIJEpogAjGSRbNEATN6+NKKIAKIBmdQ00agKbHqGwSxhNDyEOIgYJAAO9HDAyCiIAGSWDU0tZRUe-NJyitU4MADmYGjZrLm0FH20A-wQCDhw6Qo0cOPTOXkKhAOrYOub27szLHM0aDFcA0A)